# R dynamic data summary frequency with condition, map (n-1) variables to one

Tags: r, matrix, frequency

I found [a function that provides frequencies with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106346/counting-the-frequency-of-value-in-a-column/19106508#19106508) and I thought of creating a function

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(X1 ~ X2, data=dat, FUN=table))
```

I also managed to get the column names by their index number from [this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/getting-column-s-name-tp2014892p2016167.html) using `name <- names(dataset)[index]`.

---

I want to get the frequency of `Xn ~ Xstatic`, where `Xn` are the `n-1` variables and `Xstatic` is the variable of interest.

So far I made a for loop and here is my code:

```
library(prodlim)

NUM <- 100
dat1 <- SimSurv(NUM)
dat1$time <- sample(24:160,NUM,rep=TRUE)
dat1$X3 <- sample(0:1,NUM,rep=TRUE)
dat1$X4 <- sample(0:9,NUM,rep=TRUE)
dat1$X5 <- sample(c("a","b","c"),NUM,rep=TRUE)
dat1$X6 <- sample(c("was","que","koa","sim","sol"),NUM,rep=TRUE)
dat1$X7 <- sample(1:99,NUM,rep=TRUE)
dat1$X8 <- sample(1:200,NUM,rep=TRUE)
attach(dat1)

# EXAMPLE
# do.call(data.frame, aggregate(status ~ X6, data=dat1, FUN=table))

for( i in 1:ncol(dat1) ) {
  name <- names(dat1)[i]
  do.call(data.frame, aggregate(name ~ X6, data=dat1, FUN=table))  
}
```

I get the error below and I am at a loss on how to solve this. All help is appreciated.

```
 Error in model.frame.default(formula = name ~ X6, data = dat1) : 
   variable lengths differ (found for 'X6')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I would suggest not using `attach`;

2) it is meaningless to make a frequency table of your variable of interest to some of these other variables, the continuous ones, for instance, or the ones from which you have sampled from 99 and 200 possible values;

3) why would you want to combine your results into a data frame? just print them or save to a list:

```
mylist <- list()
for ( i in c('status','X2','X3','X4','X5','X7','X8') ) {
  mylist[i] <- list(table(dat1[ ,i], dat1$X6))
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm actually inserting them in a data frame because I need them in a CSV file...

Comment: Okay.. `tmp <- do.call(rbind, mylist)`; `write.csv(tmp, file = 'tmp.csv')`

Comment: Thanks, it works great! Is it possible to add which variable the values where compared against (y-axis)? I can get the order from the logs but it could cause confusion later on.

Comment: That's one of the reasons I wouldn't combine them into a data frame. This is very hacky, but `mylist <- NULL
for ( i in c('status','X2','X3','X4','X5','X7','X8') ) {
  mylist <- rbind(mylist, rbind(i,table(dat1[ , i], dat1$X6)))
}

write.csv(mylist, file = 'tmp.csv', quote = F)`

Comment: Thank you! Oh if that's the case what do you recommend?