# How to display the factor names in my descriptive statistics instead of the numbers in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

In the DataAnalyst data (from Kaggle), I am trying to show descriptive statistics of Ratings (numeric value) by state (categorical factor). I am able to successfully display everything but the state names which shows up as #s:

```
m<-aggregate(Rating~state, data=df,mean)
sd<-aggregate(Rating~state, data=df,sd)
n<-aggregate(Rating~state, data=df,length)
##summary descriptive table
(df.des <- cbind(n[,1], n=n[,2], mean=m[,2], sd=round(sd[,2],3),se=round(sd[,2]/sqrt(n[,2]),3)))
```

For df.des, I understand the n[,1] displays the # col you want. I have tried n[,2] which brings up the number/state. How can I get the table to display the names and not the numbers?
P.S. "State" is listed as characters (e.g. CA, NY, IL) and not numbers.

[descriptive statistics with numbers instead of state categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gPcW.png)

[What n looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR0ZV.png)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to apply all statistics at once in `aggregate`, this will save some pain.

```
f <- function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x), se=sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)), n=length(x))

r <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(Rating ~ state, data=df, FUN=f))
r
#   state Rating.mean Rating.sd Rating.se Rating.n
# 1     A    4.000000  3.000000 1.7320508        3
# 2     B    3.666667  1.527525 0.8819171        3
# 3     C    6.666667  4.932883 2.8480012        3
# 4     D    5.000000  4.000000 2.3094011        3
# 5     E    7.333333  3.055050 1.7638342        3
```

<sup>**Note:** To learn why we need `do.call(data.frame, .)` here, see [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21768881/6574038)</sup>

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(Rating=sample(1:10, 15, replace=T),
                 state=rep(LETTERS[1:5], 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

`cbind` by default uses `cbind.matrix` instead of `cbind.data.frame` and `matrix` can have only a single `class`.  So, if we there is any column with `character`, it converts to `character` class.  If the column is `factor`, because it is stored as integer, it gets coerced to `integer`.  To prevent that, use `data.frame` or `cbind.data.frame`

```
(df.des <- data.frame(n[1], n=n[,2], mean=m[,2], 
         sd=round(sd[,2],3),se=round(sd[,2]/sqrt(n[,2]),3)))
```

---

As a reproducible example

```
cbind(factor(letters[1:3]), 4:6) # // returns a matrix
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
#[2,]    2    5
#[3,]    3    6
```

The reason is because of coercion to `integer` storage values

```
as.integer(factor(letters[1:3]))
#[1] 1 2 3
```

If the column was `character`, it changes the whole matrix to `character`

```
cbind(letters[1:3], 4:6)
#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "a"  "4" 
#[2,] "b"  "5" 
#[3,] "c"  "6"
```

Both are incorrect.  So, either use `data.frame` or use the `data.frame` method from `cbind`

```
cbind.data.frame(a1 = factor(letters[1:3]), b = 4:6) 
#   a1 b
#1  a 4
#2  b 5
#3  c 6
```

NOTE: THis answers the OP's original question about why it didn't work

---

Multiple functions can be applied in a more flexible way in `tidyverse`.   In `base R`, `aggregate` is not an ideal function to apply more than one function as it is returns a `matrix`. In addition, if there are `NA` values, we may have to take care of the `NA` by specifying `na.action` as well as the `na.rm` argument from `mean` or `sd`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(state) %>%
     summarise(n = n(), across(Rating, 
         list(mean = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE), sd = ~ sd(., na.rm = TRUE))))
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, Thanks so much for your help I really appreciate the examples and your advice to use dplyr! The cbind.data.frame worked